# Delphi 10.4 смена цвета RichEdit не работает

Tags: delphi

Помогите пожалуйста с решением 1 вопроса. Использую такую процедуру

```
procedure TForm1.NotificationInsertText(RichEdit: TRichEdit; const atext: string; acolor: TColor; astyles: TFontStyles);
begin
with RichEdit do
begin
  SelAttributes.Color := acolor;
  SelAttributes.Style := astyles;
  SelText := atext;
end;
end;
```

для смены цвета текста в RichEdit. Если не использовать темы из вкладке Project => Options => Appearance, то цвет текста меняет всегда, как нужно. Когда я установил там тему для программы, цвета текста не меняется никак. Как решить проблему, чтобы цвет меняется в richedit при использовании темы? Включал/отключал ParentColor и ParentFont, не помогло.

Comment: А через графический редактор меняется?

Answer (score 1):

*Использую такую процедуру*

А при каких условиях она вызывается?

*Включал/отключал*

Можно и StyleElements в комбинации попробовать

++ старенький пример был, видели http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/add_re_colored_line.html
да, думаю правильно идете - отключить элемент с воздействия схемы оформления.
но там своих вылезет проблем куча.

Answer (score 0):

В новых версиях Delphi для изменения различных свойств (не только цвета) нужно просмотреть свойства `StyleElements` компонента или всей форми и поставить в `False` для возможности изменения программистом.